# Have you used the Retouch3D? What are pros and cons of it?

Tags: electronics

I teach in a high school that has a MakerBot printer. I was looking at the Retouch3D tool. I'd like to know some pros/cons from people who have used it themselves. Would you say it is worth getting for a high school?

Comment: We don't generally do broad pros-and-cons reviews. That type of on-going discussion is just not well-suited to this format. You can read more about how this works here: [The Stack Exchange Tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour). If you have a very specific question, I'm sure the folks here would love to help, but I have to close this as *too broad* for this site. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No confusion. I thought "is this something you'd recommend this product to a school" wasn't broad but I appreciate your feedback. Guess I will have to look elsewhere for this type of question.